# Printing out an exact line in a C program

Tags: c

Can you tell me, how I can print out

```
2
2 4 2
2 4 6 4 2
...
```

in a program... where N means the number of rows, and the pattern repeats so on...

I get the idea of doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c, n, col, row, val;
    printf("Provide value of N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(row = 0, col = 1, val = 2; row < n; row++, col += 2){
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++, val += 2){
            printf("%d ", val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it only does half of the work.

The output is forever ascending... and I do not want that..

```
2
4 6 8
10 12 14 16 18
...
```

How could I make it print the numbers in descending order too, when it hits the max value in a row?

Comment: I suggest you start over, and reimplement your code in smaller pieces. For example start with a simple program that only read the input, and nothing more. Then add a loop that prints `2 4 ... n`. Then add a loop that prints down from `n - 2` to get the `... 4 2` output. Then outside the existing two loops add a new loop that runs the inner loops `n` times. Then in the inner loops, instead of using `n` as the limit for the loops, use the "iterator" variable of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you don't reset `val` after the new row starts. Furthermore, it doesn't contain any logic to manage the descending sequence.

This code behaves as you expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, n, col, row, val;
    printf("Provide value of N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(row = 1; row <= n; row++)
    {
        for(val=2; val<=2*row; val+=2)
        {
            printf("%d ", val);
        }
        for(val=2*row-2; val>0; val-=2)
        {
            printf("%d ", val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some comments:

- Start with `row` 1: it will be useful as the maximum value of each row has to be `2*row`
- Within the first loop, I add two `for` cycles : the first ascending and the second descending
- The inner ascending loop has to start from `2` until the value `2*row` is reached
- The inner ascending loop has to start from `2*row-2` (not `2*row`, as we already printed that value) until the value `2` is reached (so, we check it to be greater than 0)

Comment: Thank you very much @Roberto Caboni...Your solution is fine, and thank you for the additional thoughts, they are really helpful.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not subtracting the value again, only ever increasing, and you do not reset your value after each iteration. See a running example based on your code here: https://ideone.com/j6xHZE

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, col, row, val;
    printf("Provide value of N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // Iterate through the desired rows
    for (row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        val = 0; // Reset val for each row
        // Iterate until we have reached as many columns as the row
        // number we are at
        for (col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
            val += 2;
            printf("%d ", val);
        }
        // After this continue one less iteration where we decrease
        // the value
        for (col = 0; col < row; col++) {
            val -= 2;
            printf("%d ", val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ouptuts:

```
Provide value of N: 5
2 
2 4 2 
2 4 6 4 2 
2 4 6 8 6 4 2 
2 4 6 8 10 8 6 4 2
```